# Visual Studio 2005 Deployment of cube

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, cube

I have a cube that has worked fine until last friday. Today I imported data into the tables the cube uses, did my tests if all dimensions have all necessary data also, and tried to deploy the cube.

The deployment fails and only gives this error:
Error   18  Systemfehler:       0   0
(Systemfehler means System error)
...now I would have appreciated some more text in the error message, but there is none!

So i googled a little, then decided to delete the cube on the SQL-Server and try again - same Story. So I tried out other SQL-Server, where there is no such cube up to now -again the same error.

Does anyone hav any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think its a file system error.

```
1. Stop the Analysis Services service
2. Delete everything in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\OLAP\Data\%YOUR_PROJECTNAME% folder
3. Restart the Analysis Services service
4. Connect to the Analysis Service using SQL Server Management Studio
5. Delete the Analysis Service database which you got the error
6. Re-deploy the SSAS project
```

I have tried this before and it worked for me.

Comment: thanks for the Input, I did try that be for posting. As this plus server-restarts have not brought anything, I have made the whole cube new, which was a hazzle - but I am afraid less work then Fixing the Problem...